# Using the pipe operator ("|") when executing system commands

Tags: command-line

I'd like to emulate

```
ls -tlra | grep <search term>
```

in Wolfram. I have tried

```
Module[{},
  SetDirectory[dir]
  RunProcess[{"ls", "-tlra", "|", "grep", <searchTerm>}, "StandardOutput"]
]
```

which doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to use the "pipe" operator when shelling out commands in Wolfram?

Comment: Try prepending "bash","-c" as I show in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204842/run-retrieving-stdout-without-using-runprocess).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For example:

```
RunProcess[{"bash", "-c", 
  "ls -ltr | grep wolf "}, "StandardOutput", 
 ProcessDirectory -> $InstallationDirectory]
(* "-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators None  551360 Apr  8 09:51 \
wolfram.exe
-rwxr-x---+ 1 Administrators None 2390464 Apr  8 09:52 \
wolframscript.exe *)
```

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on the accepted answer.

I often need to run some Unix pipes to prepare data that I will then input to Mathematica.  I tend to keep the data and notebooks in the same directory, so more common for me would be to use

```mathematica
(* set directory to the notebook directory *)
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]

(* grab the stdout from the pipe *)
raw = RunProcess[{
    "/bin/bash", "--login", "-c",
    "cat papers.jsonl | jq 'select (.title | contains(\"Tiger\"))'"
  }, 
  "StandardOutput", 
  ProcessDirectory -> NotebookDirectory[]
 ]
```

The original Unix pipe `cat papers.jsonl | jq 'select (.title | contains("Tiger"))'` was copied and pasted from the terminal inside an already typed `""` pair.  By doing so Mathematica will prompt you if you want to escape any quotes or backslashes (which one does).

The `--login` make the bash instance behave like the one I use on the command line.  In my case that is important because the program `jq`, used to manipulate JSON, is not in a standard location.   The file `papers.jsonl`, a collection of JSON objects, one per line, is in the same directory as the Mathematica notebook, so the `ProcessDirectory` option changes the shell's directory before its execution.

The `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]` line is typically at the top of the notebook.